# iTunes stuck on "installing" when installing .ipa files

Tags: itunes, ios, install, iphone

I have downloaded an `.ipa` file (a free game). when I trying to install it form iTunes to my device, it is stuck on installing:

[image: iTunes screenshot]

Comment: my question was do you have enough space ?

Comment: Yes, you can see in the bottom of screen shot. 23 GB FREE

Comment: Why is your game showing 1.52 Gig while on iTunes it shows 1.29 Gig ? Real Racing 3 Updated: May 27, 2014 Version: 2.3.0

Comment: `.ipa` file is 1.1 Gig but when installing it shows 1.52

Comment: Did you download the game via iTunes? If not, where did you download it.
Alternatively, try to install it on the iPhone itself using the app store

Comment: @KevinGrabher No, I didn't download from iTunes. I have downloaded it from [Here](http://dl.cafeapple.net/Games/Racing/Real_Racing_3_v2.2.0-www.CafeApple.net.ipa).

Comment: Your phone would need to be jailbroken to install that file. It is not officially supported by apple (and from the first glance at the page it is most likely piracy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very uncommon to download / install a IPA file - free of charge or not.

The IPA files are usually used for known & registered devices (e.g. beta testers) - if your device is not registered and your device is not included in the IPA profile file, then installing the IPA file will fail.

This is kind of the Apple philosophy / protection: either you have a "deep" contact to the developer who includes your device (maximum is 200 devices as far as I know), or you jailbreak (?) your device, or you use the official AppStore and trash the IPA file.

Comment: 100 devices, not 200